# Detecting last value of database after refresh the application

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am making an iPad app. I have got some problem. Actually I want to show one view at the starting of the app after launching of splash screen. I have made one checkbox on it. It will work as on/off button. Very first time launching of the app, this screen will show to the user. If user click the off button then this screen will never show to him even after refresfing the app. For it, I have made a database table in which at the starting I have stored 0 value in it. When user click button then it becomes 1. But whenever user will refresh the app it becomes again zero but I want to retrieve the last value from the database. Anyone has idea that how to retrieve last value from database table even after refreshing the app.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

You really should use user defaults for this purpose.  There is a method, registerDefaults that is used to set initial values for a default, but once the user has changed it, that initial value isn't used again on subsequent launches of the app